# ActionScript3 gotoAndPlay not finding frame.

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, frame, animate-cc

I am new to ActionScript 3, but I have a pretty good idea how to jump frames. However, I have nested frames inside a movieclip symbol and my code cannot find them. I am making a simple platforming game.

```
 ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label Stand Front Frame not found in 
scene Stand Front Frame.
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at menutest_fla::MainTimeline/frame813()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
at menutest_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToScene_3()
```

Here is my code, it is pretty simple. There are no typing errors that I have noticed. I cannot figure out why it is not working. Any help would be deeply appreciated, thanks!

```
stop();
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;


var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

movieClip_5.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_3);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed_3);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed_3);



movieClip_5.gotoAndStop("Stand Front Frame")

 function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_3(event:Event)
{
    if (upPressed)
    {
        movieClip_5.y -= 0;
    }
    if (downPressed)
    {
        movieClip_5.y += 0;
    }
    if (leftPressed)
    {
        movieClip_5.x -= 5;

    }
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        movieClip_5.x += 5;
    }
}

function fl_SetKeyPressed_3(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = true;
            movieClip_5.gotoAndPlay("Walk Forward Frame");
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = true;
            movieClip_5.gotoAndPlay("Walk Backwards Frame");
            break;
        }
    }
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed_3(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = false;
            movieClip_5.gotoAndPlay("Walk Backwards Frame");
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = false;
            movieClip_5.gotoAndPlay("Walk Forward Frame");
            break;
        }
    }
}

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cameraFollowCharacter);
function cameraFollowCharacter(evt:Event){
 root.scrollRect = new Rectangle(movieClip_5.x - stage.stageWidth/3, movieClip_5.y - stage.stageHeight/1.5, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}
```

Comment: Put this code right *above* your `movieClip_5.gotoAndStop("Stand Front Frame");` line of code:    

`import flash.display.FrameLabel;

var labels:Array = mc1.currentLabels;

for (var i:uint = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var label:FrameLabel = labels[i];
    trace("frame " + label.frame + ": " + label.name);
}
`

See what that traces out, and if one of them is the label your are expecting

Comment: What did the above code trace out?  Most likely your issue is one of scope and you are either in the wrong scene, or are targeting the wrong timeline.

Comment: Thank you sir! Using this I was able to figure out that the scope was wrong. I appreciate it.

Comment: If my answer (about scope and how to figure out if that's the problem) led to the solution of your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your spaces from your frame label (both in your code and the MovieClip's frame label).

and if not solved, try it once again with your frame number instead of label.

```
leftPressed = true;
movieClip_5.gotoAndPlay(23);
break;
```

Comment: What action do you have on menutest_fla frame 813? It caused the error!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time with this error, if you are certain there is not a typo in your frame label, the issue is one of scope.

Either the Timeline assigned to the variable/instance name `movieClip_5` isn't the one you think it is, or you are in the wrong scene.

To double check it's not a typo, and to see all the frame labels of `movieClip_5`, do the following (example code from the [documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentLabels)):

```
import flash.display.FrameLabel;

var labels:Array = movieClip_5.currentLabels;

for (var i:uint = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var label:FrameLabel = labels[i];
    trace("frame " + label.frame + ": " + label.name);
}
```

This writes to the output window every frame label from `movieClip_5`'s current scene.  If you don't see what you expect, it means **when this code runs**, you are not in the scene you expect, or `movieClip_5` is not the timeline you think it is (perhaps you want a child of `movieClip_5` like `movieClip_5.someChildsInstanceName.gotoAndPlay("Walk Forward Frame")`).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback!

It ended up being a symbol issue, where I did not have the frames nested properly within the symbol I was calling on. And it was not ultimately the code. I appreciate your help!